# Issue using .append in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap tabs markup I am trying to display a collapsible menu/accordion if window is less then 768px.

Each `<tab-content>` needs to move inside whenever each `<ul nav-tabs>` is `<li active>`. I have managed to append the  to the first `<ul nav-tabs> <li active>` although I cannot get it to move when each `<ul nav-tabs> <li active>` is clicked. **ie. only the first tab works**

How to get each active `<tab-content>` to append to each `<ul nav-tabs> <li active>` when each one is clicked?

[**Click for demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/5690/)

```
<div role="tabpanel" id="tabs-test">
              <!-- Nav tabs -->
              <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
              </ul>
              <!-- Tab panes -->
              <div class="tab-content-outer">
                  <div class="tab-content">
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /tabpanel -->
```

Should be a simple fix but I'm stuck! Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You are basically removing a `<div>` from the DOM and appending it to the `<li>` and no longer keeping track of the class management that occurs during bootstrap tabs. So, when you start, the home `<div>` is appended to the home `<li>` and made active. Then you click something else, but home is still appended to its <li>...

Comment: Thank you @ethorn10. It is exactly what's happening, although what can I do to fix?

Comment: Needs to append it to wherever an active li exists

Comment: You'll need to write your own toggle management function. Something that removes the previously appended div (Home on initial load) from the li and puts it back in the `tab-content` div and in the proper location, and then matches `.active` divs with lis. This most likely won't be pretty.

Answer (score 0):

Use *.addClass()* instead of *append()* or *appendTo()*.

*AppendTo()* insert every element in the set of matched elements to the end of the target.

Example:

```
<h2>Greetings</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>
$( ".inner" ).append( "<p>Test</p>" );
```

You can create content and insert it into several elements at once.

**I changed your example:**

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/5693/
It's worked fine but you need to config your CSS

**Source:**

http://api.jquery.com/append/
 http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: Thank you @Andre although don't know how this helps in my case. Have you seen the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/5690/)?

Comment: Just saw you updated. Each active <li> needs to display each tab-pane beneath it. At the moment only the first tab works.

Comment: My example worked replacing the class of div element ".tab-content"

Comment: I think you missed what I am trying to achieve. I think I need to explain it better although the preview in the fiddle does it justice.

Comment: ie. I need to move a div inside of another div - not add a class.

Comment: Thank you @Andre although I am trying to display an accordion type layout if the size of the window is less then 768px.

Comment: I understand. Can you use a kind of accordion navigation? This is a good example: http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/R6EAW/12/    There not append div inside another div, just toogle() and hide() div panels.

Comment: ...but I need to display Bootstrap Tabs at the desktop size.